# Prevent browsers from inserting name and password

Tags: xhtml, browser, credentials

Duplicate of [Disable browser save password functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32369/disable-browser-save-password-functionality)

Is there a way to tell the browser not to insert pre-Saved credential data into forms on websites?

For example I might have an application where I have to login first. I saved the credentials for this login.

When I now want to create a new user account in the control panel, the browser automatically fills in the values for the name and password field, although I want to create a new user.

Is there a way to stop this from happening? Thanks for your answers.

Edit: I mean that the browser fills in the saved credentials when opening the site. I do not mean offering pre-filled in values for that form. But when I open the site the whole textfield and passwordfield are filled out with my data. I'm looking for a xhtml way of doing this, so it is programming related.

Comment: If you mean that you are creating a webpage that you want to disable it in (I don't think this is the case), then add an autocomplete="off" attribute to the element. It is not standards compliant, but I think it works on most every browser that has autocomplete.

Comment: Why is this marked offensive? :-$

Comment: Why was this closed as not-programming-related?

Comment: Because this is a browser config question. autocomplete="off" is not the answer, though it is interesting to know.

Comment: Unless the OP clarifies whether he means in HTML or a browser setting then I think the benefit of the doubt applies and it should remain open.

Comment: Well, even if it were an HTML question, it would get closed as a dupe.

Comment: The example points to the config version. Sides, if it's the progrommatic question, it's a dup

Comment: Alright Kev, how about we compromise. I'll just tag is not-programming-related.

Comment: Does it matter in the long run which reason is used? Either it isn't programming related or if it is then it is a dupe and the dupe has been identified.

Comment: Thank you for editing to clarify Sebastian, but is this a question about a web page that you are writing the HTML?

Comment: Arguably, the close system needs to be refined. Especially for cases such as this one, where there's legitimate disagreement. But for now, the OP has a programmatic answer.

Comment: @EBGreen yes, it is. I'm sorry when I could not describe it better. However, I got an answer :)

Comment: Judging by the acceptance of the answer, the duplication is confirmed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From this older post the 'autocomplete' attribute may be your friend:

[Disable browser 'Save Password' functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32369/disable-browser-save-password-functionality)

Comment: I thought that at first too, but after re-reading I think he is asking for an option in his browser to turn it off for other sites that he visits.

Comment: Thanks, I did not find that entry when I searched here on SO.