# Remove auto complete on text box

Tags: html, autocomplete

I have a few text boxes on my page and find it very annoying the auto complete functionality. Is there any way to remove this from my site?

Comment: FYI/ autocomplete is a browser preference and many people, including myself, believe these preferences should be left to the user's discretion. I believe that's why your question is being downvoted, not sure though. Users should explain their downvotes.

Comment: @Matt K: For regular forms yes, but for password fields and some other cases, autocomplete messes up. This is a valid question, thought it should be clarified that it must be a crossbrowser fix.

Comment: I think this is a perfectly reasonable question, and I can see a lot of good reasons to disable it.

Comment: My use case, I have a form, I want the user to fill in with the aid of autocomplete if they wish, but I have a confirm email textbox. I want to ensure the email address entered is correct, so autocomplete is counter productive here. I want this to be a prompt for the user to check the email address potentially added by autocomplete. So this question is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 31):

## Auto Complete

As of HTML 5, the auto complete is a [form / input Attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3868299/352449) suported by all major browsers.

```
<form name="form1" id="form1" method="post" autocomplete="off" action="#">
```

Also, see here some more information about its usage:

- [W3C cheatsheet](http://www.w3.org/2009/cheatsheet/#search,autocomplete)
- [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/How_to_Turn_Off_Form_Autocompletion)
- [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533032%28VS.85%29.aspx)

---

## Auto Capitalize and Auto Correct

If you are preparing an web application or any other Smartphone friendly web page, you might be interested in knowing how to: [Disable Autocomplete, Autocapitalize, and Autocorrect](http://davidwalsh.name/disable-autocorrect).

```
<input autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" />

<textarea autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false"></textarea>
```

Comment: See more info at [w3schools.com/tags/att_input_autocomplete.asp](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_autocomplete.asp)

Answer (score 3):

Add `autocomplete="off"` as form attribute and it applies to all fields inside the form.

Example : `<form action="#"  autocomplete="off">`

Answer (score 3):

This is how you can do this

```
autocomplete="new-text"
```

Add inside you input box or textarea

Answer (score 2):

autocomplete="off" can be added as a non-standard attribute to input fields. not sure which browsers besides IE support it though.

Comment: autocomplete is in the [W3C spec](https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/input/text) so is very much a standard field.

Comment: It wasn't a standard in HTML4, which is the era this answer was written. [link to relevant SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/582244/is-there-a-w3c-valid-way-to-disable-autocomplete-in-a-html-form)

Answer (score 1):

autocomplete="off" do not support instead of that use this 'autocomplete="new-password"'

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to add the autocomplete attribute after the page loads. That's the best way I found to force Chrome to listen.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    jQuery(function() {
        jQuery('#my_input').attr('autocomplete', 'off');
    });
</script>

<input type="text" name="my_input" id="my_input">
```

Answer (score 0):

`autocomplete="off"` works in Firefox, but it doesn't work in Chromium browsers on Ubuntu, so you need to check if the browser is a Chromium browser, and if it is use `autocomplete="disabled"`, otherwise use `autocomplete="off"`.

```
var is_chrome = /chrome/.test( navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase() );
$("#mobile").prop("autocomplete", is_chrome ? 'disabled' :  'off');
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: autocomplete="off" attribute is working in firefox and chrome but it is not working in google chromium-browser in ubuntu so I have check if chromium and chrome browser then set disabled value in autocomplete attribute otherwise off value.

Comment: You were supposed to edit that into your answer, but it's OK, I did it for you.

Answer (score 0):

***Simplest way:***
Remove `name` attribute, and add always a different string in `autocomplete`.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        var randomicAtomic = Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 10) + Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 10);
        $('input[type=text]').removeAttr('name');
        $('input[type=text]').attr('autocomplete', randomicAtomic);
    }, 1000);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

use autocomplete = "off" in Html.BeginForm

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("ActionName", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "myForm", @autocomplete = "off" }))
{
 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.field, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "text-box form-control" } })
<input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```