# How to enforce making users type in all characters for identification (currently defeated by autocomplete)

Tags: asp.net, mobile, autocomplete

Here is the situation that I am in.  I have inherited an ASP.NET web application that our company members use to enter the mileage for their company cars.  When they log in, there are first asked to enter the VIN for their car.

The manager who administers the application is adamant that they *must* type in the entire VIN correctly each time.  Apparently this is because they occasionally swap vehicles and then don't tell the Fleet dept about it.  There are liability issues.

We told him it isn't practical because nobody is likely to type it in from looking at the physical VIN each time; they are going to store the number in a file and cut and paste.  So he wants us to create a little mobile app for that purpose; it's a lot harder to cut and paste with a mobile app.

Then we told him about autocomplete.  He was *not* a happy camper.

Is there any way that we can prevent the autocomplete feature from working?  If they don't know about it and it happens to be turned off in their browser, problem solved, but I don't think there is any way of forcing it off, is there?  And has anyone else ever had to solve this kind of problem?

Comment: Not really.  If the user has any control whatsoever over their browser, they can set it to do whatever they want it to do.  They can also copy/paste values any time they want.  Your supervisor is trying to use technology to solve a non-technical problem.  His approach is fundamentally flawed.

Comment: Actually I have same problem for VIN number of Vehicle.
Here are some rules: 1. 17 digits. 2. Will take out I, O, Q (any vin with IOQ are invalid) 3. There are check sum digit in VIN https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Vehicle_Identification_Numbers_(VIN_codes)/Check_digit you can use this one to do it in client or server side.

Comment: This http://stackoverflow.com/a/10538789/5104101 may help for AutoFill and http://stackoverflow.com/a/5511446/5104101 for paste

Comment: @David, I agree that it would be better to solve this problem in a non-technical manner, but technology is the only tool that we have.  Most of the users are several pay grades above mine, even up to the company's top level execs.  We can't make them do anything.  All we can do is try to create a situation where it is more work to cheat than to play nice.  Or set up little mousetraps to catch them in their cheating, so the system's admin can be alerted to a possible 'situation'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way that semi non-standard but it's often used to prevent auto-completion. I use it for payment pages where users must enter in credit cards or account numbers and such to help prevent it from storing it.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion

Specifically you could just apply it to the VIN field in this case and leave the rest

If you're using webforms, the `autocomplete="off"` here will pass through to the browser

```
<asp:TextBox ID="tbVIN" runat="server" autocomplete="off"></asp:TextBox>
```

Or if you're dealing with direct HTML in some manner

```
<input type="text" id="vin" name="vin" autocomplete="off">
```

A snippet from that site

> Setting autocomplete="off" here has two effects:
>
> - it stops the browser saving field data for later autocompletion on similar forms though heuristics that vary by browser.
> - it stops the browser caching form data in session history. When form data is cached in session history, the information the user has filled
>     in will be visible after the user has submitted the form and clicked
>     on the Back button to go back to the original form page.

This works across browsers, including older ones but there are cases where it won't. Some of the browsers override this, but normally only for login fields where the browser is using a built in password manager.