# autocomplete on form with two password fields

Tags: html, forms, autocomplete

I'm having a problem with a form with two password fields. I have a form with three input fields: name (text), id (password), and PIN (password). My browser stores the password from PIN & autocompletes it back into the id field next time I visit the page. The PIN field is initialized empty.

Is there a way to have the ID number stored as the saved password & PIN left blank? I've tried adding an "autocomplete=off" attribute in the PIN input field with no effect.

FWIW, I'm using Firefox & trying not to use javascript.

Any suggestions (or documentation on how autocomplete/password saving actually works inside any browser) would be appreciated.

Kent

Answer (score 1):

If autocomplete="off" is not working, you should add `<input type="password" style="display: none;"/>` before any password input. It will hold completed password and will not interfere with anything.

Answer (score 0):

`<input name="password" type="password" autocomplete="off">` should do it in firefox.

See this answer: [Is autocomplete="off" compatible with all modern browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3868299/is-autocomplete-off-compatible-with-all-modern-browsers?rq=1)

Did you put the *off* in quotes?

Comment: I did put the "off" in quotes. Tried several things, but was mainly surprised at how little documentation I could turn up on how browsers implement "autocomplete". Probably just searching wrong keyword, but I couldn't turn up anything about how it works, just how to turn it off.