# Firefox doesn't suggest credit card numbers

Tags: security, firefox, credit-card

I've noticed that Firefox does not suggest previously used credit card numbers. For example, lets say I have an input field where user is supposed to enter a credit card number. If they enter anything else, the form submits, and if they focus on the field again, it suggest the previously entered value(s), but if they enter a valid credit card number, it is not suggested along with the other suggestions.

I appreciate the detail, since it adds a bit of security, but how is firefox doing that? Does it check all values on all input boxes to see if they seem like a credit card number, and if they do, avoid saving them for later suggestions? Can this behavior be deactivated? And lastly, is Firefox the only browser doing that?

Comment: I think this is what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530/how-do-you-disable-browser-autocomplete-on-web-form-field-input-tag

Comment: List of browsers in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3868299/is-autocomplete-off-compatible-with-all-modern-browsers

Comment: I'm guessing since other non-CC values are remembered in that field, none of the above links are applicable. Firefox probably filters '/[0-9]{15,}/' (any string of 15 or more digits) out of the list of things that are stored.

Comment: Rox Dorentus, That is not really what I was looking for, but thanks for taking the time to reply.

Comment: Erik Nedwidek, maybe the question is confusing, but I was not really looking for browser that support autocomplete, but for those that automatically filter CC numbers. Thanks for your answer though.

Comment: Jeff Ferland, you are right, none of the answers were applicable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firefox 4.0+ does scan for credit card numbers and if found it is not stored for autofill. I don't believe this can be deactivated.

As others have suggested there are ways to ask a browser not to remember a field for autofill but it's up to the browser to respect the request.

Comment: Thanks! I noticed this behavior long ago, and I was curious about it.