# HTML refuses to check radio button by default?

Tags: html, forms

This looks like a really basic question and I've created dozens of forms, but I just can't see what the problem is here.

I have these two radio buttons:

```
<input type='radio' class='free atype' value='0' name='dutch' checked='checked'/> Free<br/>
<input type='radio' class='paid atype' value='1' name='dutch' /> Paid
```

Obviously the first one should be checked by default.

However, when I check the second one and then refresh the page, the second radio remains checked. I know this is wrong behavior, but I can't for the life of me see what I'm doing wrong.

I'm trying this on Firefox.

Comment: just a heads up, autocomplete is not a standard attribute: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/582244/is-there-a-w3c-valid-way-to-disable-autocomplete-in-a-html-form ... this is just an IE/Firefox thing

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is what's called auto complete, you can try to turn it off by adding the `autocomplete="off"` property to your inputs

```
<input type='radio' class='free atype' value='0' name='dutch' checked='checked' autocomplete="off"/> Free<br/>
<input type='radio' class='paid atype' value='1' name='dutch' autocomplete="off"/> Paid
```

You can also put it on the `<form>` the elements are in.

Comment: I see. But, since autocomplete seems to be un-standard, I guess I'm better off checking the default button onLoad using Javascript?

Comment: @robert http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3868299/is-autocomplete-off-compatible-with-all-modern-browsers and http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/form.html

Answer (score 1):

Use **Autocomplete="Off"** as one of the properties in a tag

that will make some sense for that code.