# How reset check boxes after come back to same page, then press back in browser

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

In first page have several check boxes, I select one of them, and press submit button. Submit button moves me to second page, on that second page if I press back button in the browser, I came back to the first page where the same check box is selected.

And question is how reset that check box (or all check boxes)?

I can't reset it then I click button bescause then I lost post data with php.

Comment: Similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15009597/html-refuses-to-check-radio-button-by-default/15009647

Comment: autocomplete="off" didint work

Comment: Works here http://jsfiddle.net/AeHp4/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use javascript body onunload event

```
<body onunload="clearCheckBoxes()">
```

and write clearCheckBoxes function to clear all checkboxes.

```
function clearCheckBoxes() {
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++){
        if (inputs[i].type === 'checkbox')
            inputs[i].checked = false;
    }
}
```

In order to work for IE use **onbeforeunload** event of window instead of the body onunload event:

```
window.onbeforeunload = clearCheckBoxes;
```

Comment: So if the form is submitted, the onunload is sure to run after the onsubmit so the checkboxes are still sent to the server correctly?

Comment: Now I tested it on IE and in IE it is not working? Maybe You know why?

Comment: You're right. I also used <= in _for_ statement condition clause incorrectly which should be < only.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this at the bottom of the page:

```
<script>
var chk = document.getElementById("someCheckboxID");
chk.checked=chk.defaultChecked; // set to default
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: No, then you need to loop like the other answer