# Why use autocomplete with radio buttons?

Tags: autocomplete, bootstrap-4, radio-button

I am going through the [bootstrap 4 documentation.](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/buttons/) 
What purpose does it do to set the autocomplete tag to off?
Is this something needed for bootstrap, or is it just good practice?

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-secondary active">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off" 
checked> Active
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML refuses to check radio button by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15009597/html-refuses-to-check-radio-button-by-default)

Comment: I have three answers, sort of. The duplicate question suggests that autocomplete works with radio buttons, and @Daemonleak states that it isn't. It suggests that it is good practice to turn it off, just in case, but are radio buttons affected?

Comment: The duplicate question suggests that autocomplete not only works with radio buttons, but also brings unwanted effects...

Answer (score 8):

> Unlike other browsers, Firefox by default persists the dynamic checked state of an `<input>` across page loads. Use the autocomplete attribute to control this feature.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio

Answer (score 0):

Radio inputs are not compatible with autocomplete. However, it doesn’t hurt anything to have it there. It’s up to you if you want to keep it.

Answer (score 0):

The docs are confused on this. The link posted by @dontangg states autocomplete is used on radio buttons by Firefox, but the main doc page for the `<input>` element type explicitly says the opposite:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-autocomplete

It probably doesn't hurt to include it but to me it doesn't make much sense for it to do anything on radio buttons.

Comment: Though https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete suggests Firefox might actually use it even for attributes that normally wouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

> It's about the browser stage.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function fnPickedFlow(){
    return #('input[name=pickedFlow]:checked').val();
}

$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "pickedFlow:" + fnPickedFlow() );
    // The first time return "one"
    // The second time return "two"
});
</script>

<input type="radio" name="pickedFlow" value="one" checked/>
<input type="radio" name="pickedFlow" value="two" />
```

The first time when page loads, Radio button `one` is selected by default. When changing the selection to `two` and submitting, the redirection happens. And user click browser back button (`javascript:history.back()`) to come back to this page, `pickedFlow` is pointing to `one` but the selected button in UI is `two`.

> Change code add `autocomplete off` for each of radio button to avoid the situation:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function fnPickedFlow(){
    return #('input[name=pickedFlow]:checked').val();
}

$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "pickedFlow:" + fnPickedFlow() );
    // Always return "one"
});
</script>

<input type="radio" name="pickedFlow" value="one" autocomplete="off" checked/>
<input type="radio" name="pickedFlow" value="two" autocomplete="off" />
```

Also see:
https://forum.vuejs.org/t/radio-button-retains-old-state-on-browser-back-button/97417