# Does IE 11 ignore autocomplete="off"?

Tags: html, forms, internet-explorer-11

I'm working on a mature ASP.NET/C# application (it's about three years old).  For various reasons I've recently begun using the beta IE 11.  However, when I first fired up the app in the browser, I noticed that it asked me if I wanted Internet Explorer to remember the password for this site.  This doesn't happen in any other browser the app supports, or other versions of IE, due to the presence of autocomplete="off" e.g.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" autocomplete="off">
```

Is this skunked in IE 11 (which I know is only beta, but I'm a bit worried about it)?

Comment: The "remember password?" dialog probably doesn't check for `autocomplete` anymore.

Comment: [autocomplete](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/forms.html#autofilling-form-controls:-the-autocomplete-attribute) seems to have got a whole lot more complex recently. It could be the implementation is in flux in IE11 beta at the moment.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes, IE11 deliberately ignores this attribute **on password fields** (demo in the 3rd section of this page http://enhanceie.com/test/password/passwordautocomplete.asp).

Password managers encourage strong, unique password creation per site. Unique, strong passwords are difficult to remember and type on touch devices for each site, so users rely on their password manager. IE11 still honors the `autocomplete=off` attribute on all other AutoComplete input elements (e.g. name, address, credit cards, usernames, phone, etc).

These old blog posts might set some context: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ieinternals/2009/09/10/why-wont-ie-remember-my-login-info/
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/06/03/slowing-down-disabling-accelerators.aspx

**Summarized**: When the browser doesn't offer to autocomplete a password, the user assumes that the browser is broken. They then either use another browser which ignores the attribute, or install a password manager plugin that ignores the attribute.

Note: In addition to disabling `autocomplete=off`, IE11 will also "autofill" the password if certain conditions are met-- see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn629640(v=vs.85).aspx for details.

Comment: "Summarized: When the browser doesn't offer to autocomplete a password, the user assumes that the browser is broken. They then either use another browser which ignores the attribute, or install a password manager plugin that ignores the attribute."  
most funniest cause ever ;)  
see how safari solved that "hard" problem on an elegant way (simple tooltip like hint shown about the fact that the site disabled remember functionality)

Comment: @Hofi — Safari tells about the feature disabled by the site ? Or Safari says that the site wants the feature disabled but Safari still allows the user to save the password ?

Comment: @NicolasBarbulesco Safari disables the storage of the password and tells the user why.

Comment: Plus one @Safari for creatively passing the buck.