# Disable remember password in browser in Firefox 30.0/Chrome Version 35.0.1916.153 m

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am using a Login Page which redirects to next page, but while redirecting I am getting remember password from browser side. How to disable it

the below code works in IE -8

but not working in Mozilla Firefox 30.0

and Chrome 35

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server" method="post" autocomplete="off">
<div>
<table>
<tr>
<td>UserName</td>
<td><asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Password</td>
<td><asp:TextBox ID="txtPwd" runat="server" TextMode="Password" autocomplete="off" /></td>
</tr>
 <tr>
 <td></td>
<td><asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" onclick="btnSubmit_Click" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</form>
</body>

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (txtName.Text == "user" && txtPwd.Text == "pass")
    {
        txtPwd.Attributes.Add("autocomplete", "off");

        Response.Redirect("Register.aspx");
    }
    else
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: _The ability for websites to disable the password manager using `autocomplete = "off"`  is being removed in Firefox 30_ See [Bug 956906](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=956906) Source [MDN: How to Turn Off Form Autocompletion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion)

Comment: What about Chrome Version 35.0.1916.153 m

Comment: Sorry for this. I corrected my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a browser specific feature and support has been discontinued by major browsers because of compatibility issues.
[Is autocomplete="off" compatible with all modern browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3868299/is-autocomplete-off-compatible-with-all-modern-browsers/21348793#21348793)

Answer (score -1):

Use:

```
<input onclick="request ();" type="button" value="Submit form" />
```

instead of any submit inputs and in function named: "request" call an "XMLHttpRequest" to your php file.
Example fiddle: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C94d6/).

Note: Fiddle outputs: "error: NOT FOUND", because there is no: "parse.php" in same dir. In your script you need change the name and parameters in "data" object.

Update:

```
<?php
    function decodeURIComponent ( $string ) { return rawurldecode ( $string ); }
    function encodeURIComponent ( $string ) { return ( decodeURIComponent ( $string ) === $string ? rawurlencode ( $string ) : $string ); }
    function isLogged ( $email, $password ) { return ( ( $email === encodeURIComponent ( "nobody@example.com" ) && $password === encodeURIComponent ( "reallyStrongPassword" ) ) ? true : false ); }
    foreach ( $_POST as $key => $value ) { $params [ encodeURIComponent ( $key ) ] = encodeURIComponent ( $value ); }
    // added encode checking and change API to JavaScript like
    // better security ( if JavaScript was modified )
    $count = count ( $_POST );
    if ( $count === 2 && isset ( $params [ "email" ] ) && isset ( $params [ "password" ] ) ) // security checks
    {
        $email = $params [ "email" ];
        $password = $params [ "password" ];
        /* here I check $email and $password with their hashes in MySQL file */
        $good = isLogged ( $email, $password );
        if ( $good ) { echo "<h1>Sucessfull logged in !</h1>"; }
        else { echo "<h1>Bad e-mail or password or not already registered !"; }
    }
    else { exit ( "Security critical error !" ); }
?>
```

Note: This is only an example code ...
Note: encodeURIComponent is really important in security cases.

Updated fiddle: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C94d6/1/)

Comment: Could you pls share the parse.php page.. It is not working If I use my parse.php

Comment: I am getting error like this                                        Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VAR in D:\wamp\www\example\parse.php on line 14 . I am new to PHP, My coding is C#.Net