# Rails - turn off autocomplete for text_field and password

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I just give up. I have remembered password and login for my phpmyadmin on www.xxx.com/phpmyadmin like:

```
root
asdfasfsdfs
```

Then on my aplication on www.xxx.com/model/new , I have

```
<%= form_for @model do |f| %>

 <%= f.text_field :city, :placeholder => 'Write Your city' %>
 <%= f.password_field :password, :placeholder =>'SET PASSWORD' %>


<% end %>
```

Why browser put in text_field for city "root" and in password - password for root of phpmyadmin?

How can I remove autocomplete of this fields? I try:

```
 autocomplete => 'off'
 autofocus => false
 :value => ''
 $('#field').val('')
```

Nothings work... Peoples do not see placeholder text, because fields are filled ...

ANSWER:

Ok, I make by jQuery, like this:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $('.div_class input').val('') 
});
```

So fields are filled but after load is done jQuery clear them.

Comment: Sounds like you are confused about what `autocomplete` is

Comment: How can I remove auto-fill of this fields?

Answer (score 5):

just change the syntax a little. This worked for me :autocomplete => **:off**

```
<%= f.text_field :city, :placeholder => 'Write Your city', :autocomplete => :off %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can turn off the feature by setting the [`autocomplete` attribute to `off`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_autocomplete.asp) in the form or field.

```
<%= f.text_field :city, :placeholder => 'Write Your city', :autocomplete => 'off' %>
```

However, keep in mind that the directive [is not compatible with all browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3868314/123527) and major browsers are moving towards [ignoring the attribute for password fields](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21348793/123527), (e.g [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion).)

Comment: It doesn't work, It is very complicated issue. There are so many answers. and everyone tells the same. Please suggest if any other solution ??

Answer (score -1):

**NOTE: DON'T FORGET TO RESTART THE SERVER AFTER THIS CHANGE**

```
<%= f.text_field :city, :placeholder => 'Write Your city', :autocomplete => 'off' %>
```

Comment: Server restart is not required if working locally.