# How to disable autocomplete for all major browsers

Tags: html, forms, browser, autocomplete

How do you disable Autocomplete in the major browsers for a specific input and/or the complete form.

I found this solution:

```
<input type="text" name="foo" autocomplete="off" />
```

However, this does not seem to work in all browsers. I've had problems in firefox for instance.

Edit:

My firefox issue has been resolved. That leaves the following: Can I disable autocomplete on a form or do I have to give every input autocomplete="off"

Comment: What problems have you had with which versions of Firefox?

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Quite easy :) When using autocomplete="off", it still showed the dropdown with previously entered suggestions.

Comment: you need to be more specific than that. When I use `autocomplete="off"` in Firefox, it does not show suggestions. Are you sure you don’t have e.g. an autofiller add-on installed? Does the code in the question reproduce the issue?

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Thanks for the tip! When I turn my addons off, it does work. That leaves the form issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Autocomplete` should work with the following `<input>` types: text, search, url, tel, email, password, datepickers, range, and color.

But alas, you could try adding `autocomplete='off'` to your `<form>` tag instead of the `<input>` tag, unless there's something preventing you from doing that.

If that doesn't work, you could also use JavaScript:

```
if (document.getElementsByTagName) {
    var inputElements = document.getElementsByTagName(“input”);
    for (i=0; inputElements[i]; i++) {
        if (inputElements[i].className && (inputElements[i].className.indexOf(“disableAutoComplete”) != -1)) {
            inputElements[i].setAttribute(“autocomplete”,”off”);
        }
    }
}
```

Or in jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(':input').live('focus',function(){
        $(this).attr('autocomplete', 'off');
    });
});
```

Comment: but its told in question that autocomplete="off" does not work

Answer (score 3):

You could try manually clearing text fields on page load with javascript, for example:

```
window.onload = function() {
    elements = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (var i=0; i<elements.length; ++i) {
        elements[i].value = "";
    }
};
```

This might not work if it's executed before the autofill. Another option is to generate part of the `name` attributes for your inputs randomly each time the page is rendered (and strip them out when the server handles the submit), then the browser won't try to autocomplete.

See also [Is autocomplete="off" compatible with all modern browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3868299/is-autocomplete-off-compatible-with-all-modern-browsers)

Answer (score 0):

I found this one. It hides on chrome, edge and opera

```
<form autocomplete="off">
<input role="presentation" />
</form>
```

Answer (score -2):

IE: autocomplete

Firefox， Chrome， Opera: disableautocomplete

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" disableautocomplete id="number"/>
```

Comment: Please, try to be more informative in your answer, use appropriate sentences so your solution is more readable by others.

Comment: I cannot find any reference to a HTML attribute called ``disableautocomplete``.