# Hiding password field value from inspect element?

Tags: passwords, inspect

If I inspect gmail login form, the password field value is showing in inspect area. In general how can I hide password field value showing from inspect element?

Comment: Who do you want to hide it from? Yourself?

Comment: You can't. It's an input field. The value property of an input field is going to be visible through the inspect element option of the dev tools. Possible duplicate (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30013032/prevent-user-to-find-password-through-firebug-chrome-dev-tools)