# TIll which version does html attribute autocomplete = off works

Tags: html, autocomplete

Could you please share till which version does autocomplete=off supports and what are the versions and browsers that does not support.?

Comment: See http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_autocomplete.asp

Comment: duplicate for: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3868314/4711865

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is autocomplete="off" compatible with all modern browsers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3868299/is-autocomplete-off-compatible-with-all-modern-browsers)

Comment: I suppose I made my question little more clear. Browsers Latest version does not supports autocomplete. I need to know till which version does it was supported?

Answer (score 0):

Check this reference this is showing the list of browser supporting autocomplete attrib.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_autocomplete.asp