# How can I create a text box when I enter words in text box and hit spacebar it has to make entered words into a separate phrase?

Tags: javascript, html, css

when i enter a word in text box and hit spacebar it has to make entered word into a separate phrase with closing button just like in gmail compose box.

[image: as shown in the image below]

while taking the value by document.getElementById() function, how can i get the names individually?

Comment: You can ensure autocomplete is turned off by using the autocomplete="off" attribute. But beware https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3868299/is-autocomplete-off-compatible-with-all-modern-browsers

Answer (score 4):

I think you are asking about the tag library.
There's jQuery library available for [this](http://aehlke.github.io/tag-it/)
purpose.It'll solve your problem. And there's much more you can do with this library.