# How to build a form that DOESN'T bring up the 'remember password' prompt on Firefox?

Tags: forms, firefox, passwords, remember-me

So I've built an 'Edit Personal Information' section on my website that's in development, and it seems that placing form input elements with the names 'email' and 'password' puts forward the Firefox 'Remember Password' prompt upon the form being submitted. This could be misleading due to the fact that users require to input their username to authenticate themselves on the website, not their email.

Is this normal behavior, how could I get around this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Input type=password, don't let browser remember the password](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/468288/input-type-password-dont-let-browser-remember-the-password), see also [Disable browser 'Save Password' functionality](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32369/disable-browser-save-password-functionality) Short answer: `<form autocomplete="off">` Another method would be to change the field names, even generate random ones.

Comment: So I have to ask, if you're asking for a username, why is the field called `email`?

Comment: This is the area where they update their information (name, email, address, etc). I ask for the username on login.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want [Turn off AutoComplete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/How_to_Turn_Off_Form_Autocompletion)

```
     <form name="form1" id="form1" method="post" autocomplete="off"
     action="http://www.example.com/form.cgi">
     [...]
    </form>
```

Comment: THIS dont disable the "save password" prompt functionaliy on FF