# Username and Passowrd Textboxes automatically get's filled with the data after login

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am having a little problem. Whenever i login and set Remember password option to yes, the next page contains a form and it also includes username and password textboxes. They automatically get filled with the same username and password. Why is this happening? Please Tell me how to solve it

Comment: Your browser did it, not the codes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Input type=password, don't let browser remember the password](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/468288/input-type-password-dont-let-browser-remember-the-password)

Comment: are  you using asp contorls?

Comment: It's because the id's of these items are identical to the id's of the items on the page before which is rather odd to do. Perhaps you can give them a more descriptive id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its browser property. To stop this you can set autocomplete="off" in your inupt type.

```
  <input type="text" name="Username" autocomplete="off">
```

and `AutoCompleteType="disable"` when using `asp:TextBoxes`

You can also put this on the form tag. Note this does not work consistently in all browsers.