# how to disable autocomplete on in jsp page

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, auditing

i have jsp page it have username and password.if we fill up username and password  and click on submit button then the browser asks `Remember password` then click on that it stores username and password.i donot want to store username and password in browser.i have use the `autocomplete=off` in jsp .

```
<form name="indexFrm" id="indexFrm" autocomplete="off" method="post">

<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-us">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<meta name="GENERATOR" content="Microsoft FrontPage 4.0">
<meta name="ProgId" content="FrontPage.Editor.Document">
<title>Login</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">




function login(btnName)
{


  if(window.document.indexFrm.userIdTxt.value=="")
    {
        alert("Enter User Id");
        window.document.indexFrm.userIdTxt.focus();
        return false;
    }
     if(window.document.indexFrm.pwdTxt.value=="")
    {
        alert("Enter Password");
        window.document.indexFrm.pwdTxt.focus();
        return false;
    }else{
   window.document.indexFrm.action = "../epay/abcd.jsp";
   document.indexFrm.method='post';
   window.document.indexFrm.submit();
  }

}



</script>

</head>

<body topmargin="0" leftmargin="0" background="../images/background.gif" onLoad = 'window.document.indexFrm.userIdTxt.focus();'>
<div id="wrapper">
  <form name="indexFrm" id="indexFrm" autocomplete="off" method="post">
<table width="971" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="100%" height="15" style="padding-right:4">
      <div align="right">
        <table border="1" width="10%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bordercolor="#FFFFFF">
          <tr>
<td width="50%" height="22" bgcolor="#3F9DE5">
                                                <p align="center"><a href="../htmlpages/mainbottom.htm" target="" class="newrightbtn">Home</a> </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="100%" height="15"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="100%">
      <div align="center">
        <center>
        <table border="1" width="60%" bordercolor="#7CC8FA" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
          <tr>
            <td width="100%">
              <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" class="newtexts">
                <tr>
                  <td width="100%" bgcolor="#ABDCFC" colspan="2" height="20">
                    <p align="center" class="newhead">LOGIN</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td width="100%" bgcolor="#D6EEFE" colspan="2" height="21">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td width="42%" bgcolor="#D6EEFE" align="right">User
                              Id&nbsp; </td>
                  <td width="58%" bgcolor="#D6EEFE"><input type="text" name="userIdTxt" size="20" autocomplete="off"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td width="42%" bgcolor="#D6EEFE" align="right">Password&nbsp;
                              </td>
                  <td width="58%" bgcolor="#D6EEFE"><input type=password name="pwdTxt" id="pwdTxt" size="20" autocomplete="off"></td>
                </tr>

                <td width="100%" colspan="2"><input name="stdSubBtn" type="button" class="newtexts" style="font-family: MS Sans Serif; font-size: 8pt; font-weight: bold"  onClick = 'login(this.name);' ></td>




</table>
<input type="hidden" name="frmName" value="indexFrm">
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: autocomplete="off" should work, see here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/468288/input-type-password-dont-let-browser-remember-the-password

Comment: @ Ankit already i written the code but it didnot work

Comment: Is it not working in any of the browser or any specific browser?

Comment: @Ankit it didnot work in firefox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Autocomplete works on HTML5.0, I think you are using below to that, just change your doctype tag to

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Then try.

Comment: i did not use <!DOCTYPE html> in jsp page

Comment: insert it before your <html> tag.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> this is correct or wrong

Comment: insert only <!DOCTYPE html> not the complete stuff.