# I don't want to save password when I do a login on any page

Tags: passwords, hidden, password-protection, remember-me, autosave

We always see that when we login any page then browser says that remember password or save password.

But I want to change this method. I want that browser will not ask me to save password and password box always should be empty and every time it needs to give password.

[image]

Comment: you can turn autocomplete feature of the form off which will prevent browser from saving the browser.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Input type=password, don't let browser remember the password](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/468288/input-type-password-dont-let-browser-remember-the-password)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are talking about autocomplete. You can use

`autocomplete="off"`

to not see auto suggestion.

example :

```
<input type="email" name="email" autocomplete="off">
```