# How to disable the autofill in browser text inputs selectively via code?

Tags: asp.net, html, browser, autofill

Is it possible to selectively disable the autofill feature in text fields using code?

I'm developing my custom code in ASP.Net AJAX to search for the suggestion in the database and I would like to prevent the browser suggestions from appearing when the user starts typing in the textbox.

I'm looking for a solution that works in the most modern browsers (IE 7 & 8, Firefox, Safari and Chrome). It's is ok if the workaround is in Javascript.

Comment: refer this code. it worked for me
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32369/disable-browser-save-password-functionality

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Look at the autocomplete HTML attribute (on form or input tags).

```
<form [...] autocomplete="off"> [...] </form>
```

[W3C > Autocomplete attribute](http://www.w3.org/Submission/web-forms2/#the-autocomplete)

Edit:

Nowadays - from the comments - web browsers do not always respect the autocomplete tag defined behavior. This non-respect could be surrounded with a little of JavaScript code but you should think about you want to do before use this.

First, fields will be filled during the page loading and will only be emptied once the page load. Users will question why the field has been emptied.

Second, this will reset other web browser mechanisms, like the autofill of a field when you go back to the previous page.

```js
jQuery( function()
{
  $("input[autocomplete=off]").val( "" );
} );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form method="post" action="">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="username">Username</label>
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" value="John" autocomplete="off">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" value="qwerty" autocomplete="off">
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Login">
</form>
```

Comment: `autocomplete` is now ignored by all but the most obsolete/outdated browsers

Comment: This is not a viable solution anymore.

Answer (score 11):

you can put it into your inputs:

```
<input type="text" name="off" autocomplete="off">
```

or in jquery

```
$(":input").attr("autocomplete","off");
```

Answer (score 6):

There are 2 solutions for this problem. I have tested following code on Google Chrome v36.
Recent Version of Google Chrome forces Autofill irrespective of the `Autocomplete=off`.Some of the previous hacks don't work anymore (34+ versions)

**Solution 1:**

Put following code under under `<form ..>` tag.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" >
<input style="display:none" type="text" name="fakeusernameremembered"/>
<input style="display:none" type="password" name="fakepasswordremembered"/>

...
```

[Read more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15738259/disabling-chrome-autofill)

**Solution 2:**

```
$('form[autocomplete="off"] input, input[autocomplete="off"]').each(function () {

                var input = this;
                var name = $(input).attr('name');
                var id = $(input).attr('id');

                $(input).removeAttr('name');
                $(input).removeAttr('id');

                setTimeout(function () {
                    $(input).attr('name', name);
                    $(input).attr('id', id);
                }, 1);
            });
```

It removes "name" and "id" attributes from elements and assigns them back after 1ms.

Comment: This is the only method that currently works, other answers are outdated.

Comment: Solution 1 is really smart but it doesn't work if you set the display to none

Comment: @Roy They fixed it in later versions. They are quite adamant about forcing autofill even if you don't want it. :)

Answer (score 4):

Adding an `autocomplete=off` attribute to the html `input` element should do that.

Answer (score 1):

Add the `AutoCompleteType="Disabled"` to your textbox

Answer (score 1):

This should work in every browser

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var c = document.getElementById("<%=TextBox1.ClientID %>");
        c.select =
        function (event, ui) 
        { this.value = ""; return false; }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

My workaround is to make the password field a normal textbox, then using jquery to turn it into password field on focus:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtUsername" />
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtPassword" />
<script>
    $("#txtPassword").focus(function () {
        $("#txtPassword").prop('type', 'password');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: This is a clever solution.  I did tweak this though in my case.

$('body').on('focus','.morph_to_pass',function() {
        $(this).prop('type','password');    
    });

Answer (score 1):

I have successfully tested this in Edge and Firefox.

```
<input type="text" id="cc" name="cc" autocomplete="off">
```

works for regular text input.

For passwords, you need to use autocomplete="new-password"

```
<input type="password" id="cc1" name="cc" autocomplete="new-password">
```

per [Mozilla Development Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion#preventing_autofilling_with_autocompletenew-password)

Answer (score -1):

```html
Place below code above your username control. This will work in call the browser.

<div style="margin-left:-99999px; height:0px;width:0px;">
<input type="text" id="cc" name="cc" autocomplete="off">
<input type="password" id="cc1" name="cc" autocomplete="off">
</div>
```

Comment: It doesn't answer the question. Why do you hide your fields? Why are they inside a `div` instead of a `form`? How did you find this 10+ year old question with an accepted answer?