# How to disable auto set UserName & Password when type is Password

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have developed an website in Asp.net c#. I have two login page one is for main website login and other is for Core functionality login.
My Problem is when main lagin page password is remembered and i open core functionality login page it will automatic Set user name and password of main login page to Core functionality page.
Both login page have different credential and different tables.
When i remove password type from password text box it will not fill credential, but this is not right way.

Basically, i don't want to auto fill/set credential to login page if browser saved it.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtInUserName" runat="server" autocomplete="off" Text="">
<asp:TextBox ID="txtInPassword" autocomplete="off" runat="server" Text="" TextMode="Password">
```

When i remove TextMode="Password" from Password textbox it will working fine, But it will shows password to everyone while typing.

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18208298/does-ie-11-ignore-autocomplete-off ? see http://stackoverflow.com/a/25258126/477420 for workaround (but re-read first link one more time before doing so :) )

Comment: I have already done like that : <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder2" runat="server"     autocomplete="off">. But, I don't have form control. So, I have done in asp content. But not working at all..

Comment: @FenilSuthar: autocomplete="off" should go in the `TextBox` tag, not in the `Content` tag.

Answer (score 1):

> Basically, i don't want to auto fill/set credential to login page if browser saved it.

Basically, you cannot. You can state your intention by providing the `autocomplete="off"` attribute. However, [newer browsers will gladly ignore that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18208298/87698), since they think they know better what the user wants (and in many cases, they are right).

As an alternative, you could consider moving your "core functionality" to a different location, so that the browser realizes that these are two different web applications that require different credentials. Using a different directory might already suffice (http://example.com/core).