# Do not let end-user save password

Tags: javascript, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Disable browser ‘Save Password’ functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32369/disable-browser-save-password-functionality)

Is there a standard way to prevent the end-user's web browser from saving a password using HTML or maybe JavaScript?

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32369/disable-browser-save-password-functionality

Comment: Granted this was 6 years ago, I've moved on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the non-standard `autocomplete="off"`. Your HTML won't validate with it, though.

- Info at [Mozilla Developer Center](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/how_to_turn_off_form_autocompletion)
- Info at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533486(VS.85).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

In HTML5 you can use `autocomplete="off"` but that will only work on browsers that support it