# How to avoid save password in chome 40?

Tags: html, google-chrome, autocomplete

I found same type of question [question1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3534657/do-not-let-end-user-save-password) and [question2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32369/disable-browser-save-password-functionality)

that gave as `autocomplete="off"` but this solution didn't work for chrome-40(firefox, IE, Safari work fine)

note: I didn't post code herewith that is very basic html login page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've successfully disabled Chrome 40 password save by putting the following code on the **destination page**, i.e. where the user ends up after submitting the form:

```
<form action="" method="POST" autocomplete="off">
<input type="password" name="password0" style="visibility: hidden">
</form>
```

Note that you have to use `visibility: hidden` in the CSS. Using `display: none` (or not having a password field at all) will not prevent password save. It's probably also necessary that the `name` of the password field matches the one on the form that the user submitted.

Also note that preventing users from saving *web passwords* is **evil**. I needed this because we allow users to change the password for a non-web based system via a web page, so saving the password makes absolutely no sense. For a normal web site you should **not** deprive users the right to save passwords.