# Block remember password

Tags: javascript, html, forms, autocomplete, passwords

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Disable browser 'Save Password' functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32369/disable-browser-save-password-functionality)

How can you block the remember password prompt in an HTML form?  An example is PayPal, which does not allow stored passwords.

I know autocomplete should be off and there is another trick to block the autocomplete when the browser doesn't support the attribute (make a hidden field named password).  These two methods do not work in blocking the browser from prompting to store the password however.

Comment: It's hard to explain just how much I hate sites that do that

Answer (score 1):

Send `auth` request using Ajax, then do JavaScript redirect on success.

```
// in JQuery it would be like this
$.post({
    url: '/login.php', 
    data: 'username=test&pass=test', 
    success: function(data) {
        window.href='success.php'
    }
});
```

OR

(*I haven't tried this yet*)

You can clear (*or delete from DOM*) username & password field before submit, and merge (*may be hash as well*) them into one hidden field and then do regular post.

On login page you need to reverse engineer that info again.

Comment: Any way you can think of without ajax?

Comment: If you hash the username and password, the server has no way of knowing what the username and password were, other than brute-forcing it.

Answer (score -1):

using javascript...

```
document.getElementById('usernameOrWhatever').setAttribute( 'autocomplete', 'off' )
```