# Browser offering to save passwords on HTML FORMS?

Tags: forms, html

I have a sign up page on my website. Now when a user signs up, the broswer will offer to remember the password and email on the sign up form. Which is not what I want at all, as I only want it where they will login.

Is there anyway to disable this, or is it out of my control.

```
<input type="post" autocomplete="off" />
```

autocomplete does not work.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're setting the attribute on the `<input>` element - this should be an attribute of the `<form>` element.

Answer (score 0):

A number of solutions can be found here:

[Disable browser 'Save Password' functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32369/disable-browser-save-password-functionality)

Your best bet is probably using JavaScript to bypass the default form submission mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a completely bulletproof way to turn autocomplete off.

autocomplete is a non-standard tag.  So YMMV depending on the browser.

Try setting the attribute on the form tag instead of the input tag.  I've had it work when specified on the form tag in the past.