# Remember Password alert for the site

Tags: php, firefox, mozilla

In my website login page I can't get the alert "remember password for the site".I had already enabled remember password for the site from tools->options->security->"remember password for the site" but still it is not working . I am using mozilla 3.6 version

Comment: The what? Are you using a CMS like Drupal or Joomla or what? There is no tools->options->security in plain php. Please rephrase you question!

Comment: This is probably more suitable for http://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I think @paramita mitra, is talking about browser message `remember password for the site`? Is it so?

Comment: If you run a webpage in mozilla there must be options tools->options->security

Comment: Yaa ummar is right.......then what will be the solution

Answer (score 2):

If your `login form` contains `autocomplete="off"` browser won't save your password and form history this could be a possible reason.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're confusing browser settings and website settings. Having the browser remember your users password (at least the type you're referring to) is a setting specific to each browser and not something that your website can control.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is the exact opposite of [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32369/disable-browser-save-password-functionality). See there for the answer and for more information about it.