# how to disable remember password from my site?

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Disable browser 'Save Password' functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32369/disable-browser-save-password-functionality)

In my application, I have a login page. Currently in firefox or IE, after giving the credentials and logging in it is asking to remember the password. Is there any way to disable this?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/32369/912019

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the attribute `autocomplete="off"` to the password input field.

But this is really something most users like in their browser. Why do you want to disable it? I would let the users choose if they want the browser to remember it or not, rather than forcing them.

Comment: In some banking web sites , they are disabling it.. so it should not work.. For some security reasons only we need to do that.

Comment: Solution doesn't works on firefox 30