# I don't want browser to be able to save login details

Tags: forms, browser, authentication, passwords, prompt

I'm making a login form, but I don't want browser to be able to save username & password combination.

Just like PayPal or banks.

I have heard that I could do this by using AJAX & Javascript but I'm so unfamiliar with them, so I need to ask help from you!

```
<form id="loginform">
<label for="username">Username</label>
<input name="username" type="text" value="" required="required" />
<label for="password">Password</label>
<input name="password" type="password" value="" required="required" />
<input type="button" name="doLogin" value="Login" onclick="login(this.form.username.value,this.form.password.value);" />`
```

With that login form the browser doesn't ask to save the login combo... but now I just need to know how to send the login info to PHP :P

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32369/disable-browser-save-password-functionality

Comment: The browser does not "save" anything by itself, unless some user/setting is enabled - & if it does, that would be one heck of an interesting browser!

Comment: "I don't want browser to be able to save username & password combination." please read

Comment: Please see the link provided by @Riateche which talks about the solution you are looking for. Still, like I said - the browser does not "save" anything by itself - unless there is some action/setting at the client to do so. What you are interested in finding out is - can you, as a developer, override the browser capability to allow the user to store username/password.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you require the prevention of things like *autoformer* (for Firefox). Simply change the names of the various input values to something that is different each time the user loads the form.

Answer (score 0):

As Sunny's link suggest, you can use the autocomplete attribute to prevent the browser from suggesting input for a field. So for your example:

```
<form id="loginform">
   <label for="username">Username</label>
   <input name="username" type="text" value="" required="required" autocomplete="off"/>
   <label for="password">Password</label>
   <input name="password" type="password" value="" required="required" autocomplete="off" />
   <input type="button" name="doLogin" value="Login" onclick="login(this.form.username.value,this.form.password.value);" />
```