# Don't remember passwords in browser

Tags: html, autocomplete, passwords

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Disable browser 'Save Password' functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32369/disable-browser-save-password-functionality)

Many users will use shared computers to login to my web-application. Now, I am a huge proponent of letting people browsing be in control of how they use my application, but in this case, I find it important that the users don't get the opportunity to save their passwords. These people are not tech-savvy and the chances are big they will save their passwords, giving access to their accounts without them even knowing.

I am aware of the fact that a decently configured public machine shouldn't allow saving user names or passwords, but that's not under my control. I'm also aware of `<input autocomplete="off" />`, but that only works in certain browsers (not firefox, for instance).

Is there a way to turn of the "remember password" feature that will work in most (if not all) browsers?

Comment: I recommend trying http://stackoverflow.com/a/2555771/638544 (a late arrival answer to the question Marko mentioned).

Answer (score -2):

Autocomplete on the input statement is the only option I know. What you can do is write a Javascript function that will retrieve all input statements and add the attribute autocomplete off.

jQuery is:

```
$('input').attr('autocomplete','off');
```

Comment: And this will disable autocomplete on all fields rather than just the login form ones.