# Clear form input value after page reload in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I have a problem with login form field in Google Chrome browser. I have a form with input and I want to his value was empty after page reload (refresh). I used jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form input[name=user_login]").val("");
})
```

but in Chrome this solution doesn't work, and the field is set to remembered value.

Answer (score 5):

If you set the attribute autocomplete=off, the content will never be stored.

Check the documentation:

- http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_autocomplete.asp
- http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/input/text

Comment: I know this is a super old question, but this solution just worked for me and saved me a huge headache. After entering a coupon code, if someone went to a different page and then came back, the code would still be in the box but would not be recognized by my javascript (knockout) ... with autocomplete=off added to the input the code is gone when they return to the page. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

try this in html

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
```

refer this link for further information http://www.i18nguy.com/markup/metatags.html

------edit1-----

try this fiddle in chrome:

http://jsfiddle.net/nQ5sQ/1/

I have done by id .. but It works completely fine, that is no cache issue, and when your page is ready and you fired jQuery script on it, after that no caching is done. even your hypothesis seems to be incorrect. Please post same html and jquery code to debug

Comment: If still it dosent work, write your html and jquery code in fiddle or post it here.

Comment: Code is big :) but his simple version is on http://jsfiddle.net/nQ5sQ/4/ but to see the problem is not so easy. I don't know when the Chrome cache this data...

Comment: I reproduced your bug , this will happen only when user has saved his username and password.check this updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/nQ5sQ/10/

Comment: also check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32369/disable-browser-save-password-functionality , for auto-complete off functionality