# Control what domain the browser associates with a remembered password

Tags: html, forms, passwords, cross-domain

When I submit a form with a password field in, for example, Firefox, the browser asks me if I'd like it to remember the username and password for me. For example, logging into gmail in Firefox, I get this message in a popup:

> Would you like to remember the password for "markamery@gmail.com" on google.com?

with 'Remember password', 'Not now' and 'Never for this site' options.

I'm developing a plugin that will be used to provide a service on multiple websites. Users will have an account on our `mysite.com`, and our clients, like `someclient.com`, include a Javascript script from `mysite.com` on their webpages which adds our content and functionality to their page, including a login form that users can use to sign in to our site. (The actual mechanics of the login process are all handled with iframes, AJAX and HTML5 `postMessage`s, not that it matters).

When users log into our plugin on `someclient.com`, I want their browser to prompt them to remember the password on `mysite.com`, and when they see our login form on `someotherclient.com`, I want it to be autocompleted with the same username and password that they entered into it on `someclient.com`. However, currently, they get a prompt asking

> Would you like to remember the password for "yourname" on someclient.com?

instead, which isn't what I want.

Is what I want possible, and if so, how?

Comment: The only (ugly) solution I see would be to have the login form being in an iframe instead of loading it with javascript...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting the form inside an iframe will cause Firefox at least to associate any stored passwords with the domain of the iframe instead of that of the main page. You can communicate with the iframe using [postMessages](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.postMessage).

Just have the iframe catch the form submit event, serialise the content of the form, and send it to the main window via postMessage; then the main window can grab the content of the form from the message and handle it using Javascript.

Of course, even in simple cases this is a fairly ugly hack, and if there are complicated interactions between content in the iframe and content or code in the main page, then trying to handle them all properly via postMessage may result in a quick descent into pain and spaghetti. If the value of having cross-domain password autocompletion is low and the main issue is that having a remember password message featuring the wrong domain name is bad, then consider simply disabling the feature altogether instead of mutilating your codebase with hacks to fix it. You can disable it by setting the 'autocomplete' attribute of the form to 'off', as described here: [Disable browser 'Save Password' functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32369/disable-browser-save-password-functionality)