# Turning off the post-refresh auto-complete new browser functionality

Tags: html, browser, autocomplete

I noticed that new browsers (I'm talking especially about Firefox) have this after-refresh remember inputs' values.

How can I turn it off? I noticed that setting autocomplete to off helps but I don't want to do this on every single input / textarea / etc. I make. Is there some overall trick for this?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/How_to_Turn_Off_Form_Autocompletion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put this attribute on the form tag

```
<form autocomplete="off" action="...">
   //Your form inputs

</form>
```

It was already asked on the forum: [disable browser save password functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32369/disable-browser-save-password-functionality?rq=1)