# How to supress the 'Do you want the browser to remember this password' confirmation?

Tags: android, dialog, passwords

I am creating an ASP.Net MVC 4 mobile web application and on Android 4.0.4 a very annoying confirmation dialog box is appearing every time I have a password on a form.  I click "Never" on the dialog box and it makes no difference.  I see the dialog every single time.  It kind of ruins the mobile web experience to see this constantly.

What can I do programmatically, if anything, to suppress this dialog box?  I save the password automatically to localstorage so there is never a need for them to see this dialog box.

The dialog box says this:

Confirm:  Do you want the browser to remember this password? (Now/Remember/Never)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is very similar to [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32369/disable-browser-save-password-functionality), where the asker didn't seem to be discussing one platform specifically. However, I think that taking a look at the accepted answer and trying that would be a good first step.

The suggested method there was to set the `autocomplete="off"` attribute on the `form`, to indicate to the browser that data entered should not be remembered ([MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/How_to_Turn_Off_Form_Autocompletion?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=How_to_Turn_Off_Form_Autocompletion)). With any luck, the Android browser will take note of that attribute and not offer to store the password.