# Is there a way to become aware of an input being autofilled as a result of the built in "remember password" browser functionality?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Browsers like Firefox or Chrome offer to remember the password when you login for the first time on a page; this functionality autofills the corresponding user/password combination in the login form the next time the user visits said page.

My question is, is there any way to become aware that the browser has autofilled these fields? the event `change` does not fire; in fact, according to [monitorEvents](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/commandline-api#monitoreventsobject_events) *nothing* fires. I've resorted to use an interval that periodically checks whether the fields are empty or not, but is there a better way?

Comment: `in fact, according to monitorEvents nothing fires.` - isn't that the answer to your question?

Comment: @Ian well yes, but I just wanted to make sure I'm not missing something trivial, since it seems something so basic it's hard to believe browser vendors would overlook it.

Comment: @Ian actually I'm going to rephrase the question.

Comment: I don't think there's a need for the browser to expose an event, because I'm guessing it happens on/before page load. So just check the values after the elements have rendered (safe to do on page load), and if they're empty (or if their `.value` is equal to their `.defaultValue`), nothing was saved/loaded. If they're filled, the browser did it. That's not all 100% reliable, but maybe I'm misunderstanding how the browser handles it

Comment: I think this could be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32369/disable-browser-save-password-functionality

Comment: @Ian as far as I've observed this is correct *except* when the user has several user/password combinations saved. In this case, the fields don't get autofilled on load, but rather the password gets autofilled when the user chooses an username, which can happen at any point in time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am quite sure Chrome does fire the change event. I have experienced it recently (by accident). It is also already documented in [Chromium Issue 135307](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=135307).

Not sure about other browsers, but if you are write a periodic check will probably be the only solution. [This code](http://furrybrains.com/2009/01/02/capturing-autofill-as-a-change-event/) seems solid.