# Can a browser learn a username/password during account creation?

Tags: html, forms, authentication, passwords

I received a bug report this morning that browsers were offering to remember the password from our website's sign up form, but not regurgitating it on the login form afterwards.

My initial suggestion was to disable autocomplete on the password field of the signup form so that users wouldn't have the option to store credentials until they logged in for the first time.

However, my project manager asked me to research exactly that, whether or not it's possible to have browsers store credentials after submitting an account creation form and then properly fill in the login form upon later visits to the site?

Besides this convoluted explanation, I don't even know where to begin researching, so I'm turning to the community to see if you guys can point me in the right direction, or at least give me the right words to search for.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you disable autocomplete on one field or complete  tag?

[Disable browser 'Save Password' functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32369/disable-browser-save-password-functionality)

```
<form id="loginForm" action="login.cgi" method="post" autocomplete="off">
```

Comment: No, like I said, that was my quick-fix to satisfy the UX bug, but my project manager wanted to to find out if this was even possible.  I've been looking at other questions on here and I know that the username and password fields have the same "name" attribute ("username" and "password," respectively) but different "id" attributes.  Would making the id's the same across the whole site enable what I'm trying to accomplish?

Comment: Yep, that helped loads.  We ended up realizing that the site was already doing what the project manager wanted, but he couldn't see it on his machine without first clearing his browser.  Thanks!!