# How can I prevent a browser from saving a password to say keychain

Tags: html, http, autocomplete

I notice many sites do not allow the browser to autocomplete a password field. I know that the 'input' tag can have an attribute called 'autocomplete' which can be 'on' or 'off'. But is there a better and safer way for a site to request that the user must enter the password manually and preferably not to store it in 'keychain' or equivalent?

Comment: See here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/218453/1873387

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disable browser 'Save Password' functionality](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32369/disable-browser-save-password-functionality)