# How to disable browser prompt to remember the password

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have to disable browser prompt to remember the password on login form, I have tried AUTOCOMPLETE="OFF" but it doesn't work

Comment: This is functionality of browser you can't control

Comment: You can't. The settings in a user's browser are their concern, not yours.

Comment: Try this links. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32369/disable-browser-save-password-functionality. This will help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please share your code. Especially that password tag.

I have faced the same problem. But this has fixed by below code.

```
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Password, new { @id ="Password", @Placeholder = "Password", @type = "Password", @required = "required", @Value = "", @autocomplete = "off" })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this
HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="password" required autocomplete="off">
```

and JS:

```
function validate() {
    $("input[name='password']").attr("type", "password");
}
$('input[name="username"]').on('keyup click', validate);
$('input[name="password"]').on('keyup click', validate);
```