# Prepopulate password field in devise/formtastic Login page (Rails 4/formtastic/devise 3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, formtastic

when I log into my account on google or yahoo, as soon as I put a value in the field 'email', the password gets populated.

How can I do the same on my Rails app's login page (i use devise and formtastic gem).

Do I need to add something like below?

```
:input_html => { :xxxx => true }
```

Currently, it does not do it: i need to write again and again their passwords.

thanks for any help.

Comment: This is not from rails. This is your browser saving your password for you. To save password for your app, click 'Save Password' in the yellow bar in the browser for localhost. If you do not see it, then you might have clicked 'Do not save for localhost' sometime in the past.

Comment: ok. silly me. thanks. thought that maybe it was sth i had to activate like :input_html => { :autocomplete => "on"}

Comment: Np, it is usually the other way around with [autocomplete off](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32369/disable-browser-save-password-functionality)