# How to disable save password popup in all major browser (IE,FF,Safari,Chrome)

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox, authentication

I am working in some security domain login page, they don't want any kind of automatic save password prompt from browser.
I tried using autocomplete="off", but in latest browser it's not supported. I am looking for any script which could run on browser just after loading the page, so that the save password popup don't come. 
Kindly help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disable browser 'Save Password' functionality](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32369/disable-browser-save-password-functionality)

Comment: I already tried that, its no longer supported in any modern browser.

Comment: do you have solution for single page application website ??????