# Angular JS/Django REST Change Password module issue. Browser interfering with my code

Tags: javascript, angularjs, django, passwords, authorization

I'm new to angularJS.
I am using Django REST framework as my backend API and im trying to implement change password of a user.

I have a form that contains 2 input[password] fields, one for current password and other for new, and a button.

Now as soon as i click submit the browsers pops up a window that asks me "Change password for which user." and the list is made with the saved users and their passwords i have in my browser.

This is happening only when i an giving input field type = "password" and not when im giving it a type = "text".

Can someone help?

This is my HTML View.

```
 <form name="change_pass"  ng-submit="changePass(user)">
     <md-input-container class="md-accent md-hue-2">
        <md-icon class="material-icon">lock</md-icon>
        <input ng-model="user.currentPass" type="password" placeholder="Current Password" >
      </md-input-container>

      <md-input-container class="md-accent md-hue-2">
        <md-icon class="material-icon">lock</md-icon>
        <input ng-model="user.newPass" type="password"  placeholder="New Password" >
      </md-input-container>

      <md-button type="submit" class="md-raised md-primary">Submit</md-button>
</form>
```

This is my JS(Controller)

```
$scope.changePass = function(user){
        AuthService.changePassword(user);
}
```

This is my AuthService

```
Authorization.changePassword = function(user){
        var id = $cookies.get('user');
        var postData = {
            "newpassword": user.newPass,
            "username": id,
            "currentpassword": user.currentPass
        }
        $activityIndicator.startAnimating();
        $http({
            method: 'PUT',
            url: CHANGE_PASSWORD+id+'/',
            data: postData,
            headers: {'Authorization': 'Token ' + $cookies.get('token')}
        })
        .success(function(data, status, header, config){
            $activityIndicator.stopAnimating();
            toastr.success("Password Sucessfully changed!", " Security");
        })
        .error(function(data, status, header, config){
            $activityIndicator.stopAnimating();
            toastr.error("Your Password could not be changed", " Security");
        });
    }
```

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many browser have an auto detection of "standard login / password" forms. When they detect a submit on this forms, they show this kind of dialog.

Angular and Django can't really do anything for you. You'll find a response here : [Disable browser 'Save Password' functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32369/disable-browser-save-password-functionality)

Comment: Thanks for the lead!! Setting autocomplete="off" worked for me in this case.