# ASP.Net MVC - Stop auto complete password

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an existing asp.net mvc web application which I would like to stop browsers from auto remembering passwords for next time.  Can I do this without needing to change the input autocomplete="off" on the password as whilst I can see this should resolve future ones any one who has already done this action can probably still login as the password is cached.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed `autocomplete="off"` will do the trick. You'll see it being used here in SO as well (top right):

```
<input style="display: inline-block; width: 188px; max-width: 188px;" name="q" placeholder="search" value="" tabindex="1" autocomplete="off" maxlength="240" type="text">
```

You can add it to your input using Razor:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Input, new { autocomplete="off" })
```

You can also target all of them at once with jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input:text, form").attr("autocomplete", "off");
})
```

For the caching part, have a look at this excerpt from ["How to Turn Off Form Autocompletion" (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion) (the whole document is worth a read):

> Setting `autocomplete="off"` here has two effects:
>
> - it stops the browser saving field data for later autocompletion on similar forms though heuristics that vary by browser.
> - it stops the browser caching form data in session history. When form data is cached in session history, the information the user has
>     filled in will be visible after the user has submitted the form and
>     clicked on the Back button to go back to the original form page.
>
> In some case, the browser will keep suggesting autocompletion values
>   even if the autocomplete attribute is set to off. This unexpected
>   behavior can be quite puzzling for developers. The trick to really
>   force the no-completion is to assign a random string to the attribute
>   like so :
>
> `autocomplete="nope"`
>
> Since this random value is not a valid one, the browser will give up.

You should also check if this behavior is consistent between all major browsers (depending on what browser support you are after).

**Update**: Michael Liu has noted in the comments that *"Modern browsers ignore the autocomplete attribute on password fields"*, in which case I am not aware of a legitimate solution.

You could try placing an additional `input` field of type `password` on top of your actual one and set it to hidden, the browser should attempt to autocomplete that instead:

```
<!-- before your actual password field -->
<input style="display: none;" type="password" name="pwdplaceholder"/>
```

...it is however messing with browser behavior which is not best practice.

Also have a look at [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32369/disable-browser-save-password-functionality) (shared by Michael Liu in the comments).

Comment: Has this actually answered the question? From OP: "I can see this should resolve future ones any one who has already done this action can probably still login as the password is cached."

Comment: Modern browsers ignore the `autocomplete="off"` attribute on password fields.

Comment: @MichaelLiu isn't what `autocomplete="nope"` per the excerpt above is supposed to achieve?

Comment: @trashr0x: That doesn't work either. I suppose I should have said *Modern browsers ignore the `autocomplete` attribute on password fields.*

Comment: @MichaelLiu is there a real workaround then? How about hidden input fields to trick the browser to fill those instead?

Comment: @trashr0x: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32369/disable-browser-save-password-functionality (and ignore the accepted answer).

Comment: @MichaelLiu thanks, I believe the non-accepted answers propose similar approaches to my update above. I'll update accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using this ([Preventing autofilling with autocomplete="new-password"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion#preventing_autofilling_with_autocompletenew-password)):

```
autocomplete = "new-password"
```

For example:

```
@Html.PasswordFor(m => m.NewPassword, new { @class = "form-control", autocomplete = "new-password" })
```

And this is the Browser Compatibility:
[image: Browser Compatibility]