# How can I deactivate remembering values for inputs?

Tags: html, css, input, browser-cache

I have a input like this:

```
<input name="username" placeholder="Email" type="email" autocomplete="off" />
```

As you see I've set `autocomplete` attribute to `off`. But still when I open that page, the previous value is there:

[image]

Well how can I avoid that? Actually my problem is with ugly-background-color-input. When I change its value, it looks like this:

[image]

Anyway how can I deactivate caching for inputs?

Comment: Easiest way is to remove the `name` attribute.

Comment: @Jeff Well then how can I get input's value in the PHP? `$_POST['what name?'];`

Comment: Looks like you have stored login credentials in your Chrome.

Comment: You'd have to hack it by intercepting the form submission with JS, construct a hidden form and submit it.

Comment: @str True .. But I haven't stored that, The browser has done it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable browser 'Save Password' functionality](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32369/disable-browser-save-password-functionality)

Comment: The browser does not just store the credentials. It asks you and you have to confirm that.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15738259/disabling-chrome-autofill

Comment: @Jeff That would be fine .. But unfortunately I don't use AJAX.

Comment: That wouldn't be AJAX, it would be constructing a form and calling submit on it, triggering an actual form.

Comment: Regardless it's a dirty hack for such a small issue :/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12374442/chrome-browser-ignoring-autocomplete-off#answer-30873633

Comment: @Jeff Well what happens for those users which have disabled-JS for their browsers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably you also a have a password field on the page? If not you can generate a random field name and get the value from the request object's key/value collection (maybe using a known prefix).

After looking at every answer to do with disabling autocomplete and trying around 20 combinations, the following was found to work on all current browsers (including latest Firefox, Chrome, IE 11 & IE Edge)

Place 2 dummy inputs (1 text and 1 password) with no names and no tabbing at the top of your form, but style them to be hidden (e.g. placed offscreen, but not actually `display: none`)

e.g.

```
<input tabindex="-1" style="left: -9999px;" type="text">
<input tabindex="-1" style="left: -9999px;" type="password">
```

Even the smartest browsers, which look for the first password field (regardless of its name) and attach the autocomplete to the previous input, will work with this.

Answer (score 2):

try to do following :

```
<form autocomplete="off" ...></form>
```

it may work... or you can do this too.

```
$('#textfield').attr('autocomplete','off');
```

or use `autocomplete="false"`, instead of `autocomplete="off"`

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned in your question that the background color of your input box is your problem, then you can change it the way you want.

You can use:

```
input:-webkit-autofill {
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0px 1000px white inset;
}
```

Which will change the background to white. Or you may change it to any color you like.

Answer (score 0):

when it is just about the design try

```
input:-webkit-autofill {
    transition: background-color 5000s ease-in-out 0s;
}
```

in your css

Unfortunately Google chrome change it`s autocomplete settings with every new release. When you want to disable them now you have to update your solution everytime to prevent it in further versions
**Edit:**
The only thing you can do to stop autofill and remembering passwords completely is giving IDs without "name" or "password" in it