# How do I disable browser's "save your password" option from my website's users?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I have a login for like this:

[image]

As you see, my username and password are saved in those inputs. I want to know, is that possible to disable *saving password* property of the browser by JS or HTML or whatever?

---

**Note:** Using `autocomplete` attribute isn't useful to do that:

```
<form autocomplete="off" ...>
    <input name="username" placeholder="Email" type="email" autocomplete="off" />
</form>
```

As you see, both the `form` and the `input` have `autocomplete="off"` attribute, but still saving password happens.

Comment: redirect('[here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32369/disable-browser-save-password-functionality)')

Comment: @John Well the accepted answer in your link doesn't work for me.

Comment: The accepted answer seems outdated, but this answer from the same question may work for you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25111774/519413. Other than that I don't believe there is much you can do as the functionality is enabled at the browser level by the user

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Very and very good `:-)` I enjoyed. Just one thing: Why not using `style="display:none"` for that input instead of wrapping it into *div* ?