# How can I hide an element?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to disable browser 'Save Password' functionality (my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38222118/how-do-i-disable-browsers-save-your-password-option-from-my-websites-users?noredirect=1)). To do that, I just added a new input `type="password"` field inside the form, So this is the code:

```
<form method="post" action="yoururl">
    <input type="password" style="display:none"/><!-- Making "Save Password" disable -->
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username"/>
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password"/>
</form>
```

**Note:** Using `autocomplete=false` won't work on modern browsers. So please don't suggest it. In fact I'm trying to use [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32369/disable-browser-save-password-functionality/25111774#25111774).

**Well what's the problem?** When I hide that useless input by `display:none`, it doesn't work *(I mean still that saving password option is there.)*. But when I hide that useless input by `visibility:hidden`, it works.

As you know visibility property takes up space on the page which I don't want that. So how can I hide that useless input to both hide it and remove its space?

- `display:none` is good, but destroys my purpose of adding that useless input.
- `visibility:hidden` isn't good because it takes up space on the page.

So is there the other way?

Comment: `position: absolute; left: -9999px`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yes it works, but seems really abnormal *(ugly)* `:-)`

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/video-screencasts/142-hiding-things-with-css/ Choose one ;)

Comment: It's not ideal, but it's all you can do in cases where an element has to take up space in the DOM but you don't want it to be seen. It also works for pre-loading images too.

Comment: You can add `pointer-events: none` if you wish to make the `<input>` disabled for mouse interactions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many possible solutions.

One might be:

```
input[type='password']:nth-of-type(1) {
visibility: hidden;
width: 1px;
height: 1px;
}
```

Comment: Why not `0px` ? :)

Comment: I wasn't immediately sure if the browser would accept that, but `width:0; height:0;` appears to be fine after all.

Comment: @Rounin There is a difference in fact. If you declare width and height to 0px, the browsers will think the element is `display: none`, and the screenreaders will not be able to use the element.

Answer (score 1):

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15855858/6525260).

I think method 1 is best for you, which is setting `width` and `height` of element to 0.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the autofill trough this `autocomplete="new-password"`

But if you want to delete the space it take just `position` it as `absolute` and hide it behind the body with `z-index: -9999;`

```
.fakepassword {
    visibility: none;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -9999;
}
```

Comment: `autocomplete="new-password"` works perfectly .. Thank you .. upvote