# Django crispy-forms disable browser's 'Save Password' popup

Tags: django, django-crispy-forms

I have a Django ModelForm (with a password input), rendered by the crispy-forms module.

Every time I submit the form, browser asks if it should remember the password.

Anyway it is only a ModelForm (not a LoginForm). How to get rid of this popup?

I found a possible solution here:
[Disable browser 'Save Password' functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32369/disable-browser-save-password-functionality)
...but how to add a attribute to a crispy-form (not to a input)?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a `FormHelper`, you can set `attrs` ([docs](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/form_helper.html#helper-attributes-you-can-set)).

For example to set `autocomplete="off"` as in the answer you linked to, you would do:

```
class ExampleForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ExampleForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper(self)
        self.helper.attrs = {'autocomplete': 'off'}
```