# Disable Autocomplete feature/Manage password dialogue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, security, autocomplete

Is it possible to remove chrome/safari autocomplete feature , which asks to store password once you logged in to the application?

I have tried adding "autocomplete=off" in both form and input fields

```html
<form id="formforlogin" autocomplete="off">
 <input id="usernameforlogin" type="hidden" name="usrnm" autocomplete="off"/>
 <input id="passwordforlogin" type="hidden" name="psswrd" autocomplete="off"/>
 </form>
 <table style="margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;">
   <tr>
     <td>Username</td>
     <td><input id="usernameforshow" type="text" placeholder="user" autocomplete="off" /></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>Password</td>
     <td><input id="passwordforshow" type="password" placeholder="password" autocomplete="off'/></td>
   </tr>
```

After adding the above snippet as well i am not able to get rid of autocomplete feature of chrome , which is asking to save password dialogue as soon as you login. My application is built using angular js and the routing is done using angular-ui-router.

It will be very much helpful if somebody helps to solve the above issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chrome Browser Ignoring AutoComplete=Off](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12374442/chrome-browser-ignoring-autocomplete-off)

Comment: You should put your password input field out of the form. and assign value on form submit. because browser by default will ask to save your password when it encounters USERNAME and PASSWORD combination.

Comment: Possible duplicate :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32369/disable-browser-save-password-functionality

Comment: @saravanabawa I have tried the same but still it is not fixed my problem

Comment: @YanMayatskiy i have actually added as mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12374442/chrome-browser-ignoring-autocomplete-off but it didn't worked

Comment: @SreekanthG as you can see, chrome is not addressing the autocomplete off as we would like it to, the question have many answers that might work, try them all, stackoverflow.com/a/38961567/3845972

Comment: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=587466

Comment: @SreekanthG Make your code correct and clear. In your example username and password fields are out of form. Input type hidden dont accept autocomplete="off" but you placed inside form. After fixing it then go further.