# Symfony: How to disable form fields autocomplete?

Tags: symfony

I used this in twig :

```
{{ form_start(form, { 'attr': {'autocomplete': 'off'} })  }}
```

and this in the controller action :

```
'attr'=>array('autocomplete' => 'off'
```

But the autocomplete still not disabled!!!!

Comment: Did you clear the Symfony cache in both environments, dev & prod?

Comment: Also, I've seen this issue before, especially with Chrome and was told to set the entire form to autocomplete, that may not be feasible for you, but here's the SO link, I hope this helps.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32369/disable-browser-save-password-functionality/23927796#23927796

Comment: even after clearing the cache it still doesn't work!!!

Comment: What you mean by "doesn't work"? Is there no `autocomplete` attribute in field html output?

Comment: nooo i want the autocomplete to be OFF but it still work!!

Comment: How does the rendered HTML look like? Is there an `autocomplete` attribute with the value `off`?

Comment: this how it looks like in my form : {{ form_start(form, { 'attr': {'autocomplete': 'off'} })  }}

Comment: Susan, you are not listening to some good suggestions. What is being asked is, when you check the rendered html with your settings, have you checked if `autocomplete` actually gets set at all? You should at least do this test and provide feedback.

Comment: yes autocomplete gets sel att all the fields, that what i meant by "it doesn't work' because i've set it to false in all the fields of the form

Answer (score 10):

UPDATE:
If you are using symfony 4 the proper way is using `off`

```
'attr'=>['autocomplete' => 'off']
```

Comment: I don't think that's a matter of symfony version. The attr will print out exactly what you put there into the html element. If "off" works better then that's likely a matter of html standard that the browser responds properly to. Putting "disabled" will have symfony print that out into the html element instead. If your browser responds to that, you're lucky. Current version of chrome wants "off" like you say =)

Answer (score 7):

You can use :`'attr' => ['autocomplete' => 'disabled']`

Comment: This must be the accepted answer. This works perfectly in Symfony 2.8. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For `choiceType` field, use:

```
'choice_attr' => function($choice, $key, $value) {
    return ['autocomplete' => 'off'];
}
```

Source: https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#choice-attr

Answer (score 0):

For password fields, use `new-password` rather that `off`