# how to disable remember password popup in all browser

Tags: javascript, asp.net

How to disable Remember password popup in all the browsers when logged in?
I tried `autocomplete="off"`, but it is not working fine.I need a help.

Thanks and Regards.

Comment: I think you cannot do this, If you are able to do with one browser but for all browser you cannot do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SET Auto Complete property to off at form level or field level

`<form action="something.php" method="post" autocomplete="off">`

`<input type="text" name="usrname" autocomplete="off">`

for more refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32369/disable-browser-save-password-functionality)

Comment: I already tried this one still it's not working