# How to disable "Save Password" notification in any browser programatically?

Tags: javascript, java, html, spring-mvc, mozilla

I have used multiple permutation and combination to disable Save Password notification in Browser one of them is autocomplete="off". But it doesn't work in my system. Please, suggest me !!!

Comment: don't use type="password" maybe?

Comment: or you could use https

Comment: Why would you want to force it disabled? It's a handy feature and should be left to the user whether to accept it or not. I would hate a site that prevents Chrome from remembering my password and force me to enter it every time. Nobody likes passwords.

Comment: This question have already been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32369/disable-browser-save-password-functionality

Comment: If we are using any banking site, then in this scenario we never get Save Password because it might affect the security of application or user.

Comment: Well, my password is saved on my banking site, I appreciate it and I would hate my bank if it forced me to type it every time. Why don't you allow this freedom to the user, instead of forcing people to comply to your choices?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is still not possible :( 
Users have to manually turn this off...

But you can stop the popup from showing up:
How?
Don't use type="password"

Use

```
type="text"
```

Instead

Comment: Not a good solution IMHO since the text you enter is not hidden.

Comment: @C.Champagne it's how you can disable it, but disabling the popup in this way isn't the most efficient because the text isn't hidden any more. But if it isn't such a NOT GOOD solution can you than please give me a better one

Comment: Sorry I missed the fact the OP mentioned that  `autocomplete="off"` doesn't work. I think however that it is better to leave the situation 'as-is'