# Prevent browser from asking to save login info when the form is invalid

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I've got a simple login form with the absolute basics in place for front-end validation.  It just checks that the fields aren't blank and that the email is in the most basic correct format.  When the form is invalid I prevent the `submit` behavior.

When I enter something into both fields so they aren't blank, but the email is still invalid, the form is not submitted, yet I am still prompted by browsers to save my credentials.

[image: Firefox Credential Manager for invalid form]

**How can I prevent this from happening when the form is invalid and hasn't yet been submitted?**  I still want this feature to be offered to users, but only when the form is actually submitted.

Here's the basics of how I've set this up:

HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="" onsubmit="return validateForm()" novalidate>
  <input type="text" id="email" required autofocus>
  <input type="password" id="password" required>
</form>
```

JS:

```
function validateForm() {
  var isValid = true;

  //validation logic goes here...

  return isValid;
}
```

Here's a working demo: https://codepen.io/chrismbarr/pen/awmVyq
Enter an invalid email and something in the password field to trigger this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable browser 'Save Password' functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32369/disable-browser-save-password-functionality)

Comment: This occurs only on Firefox. I tested it on Chrome and Safari, and both work as you want them to work.

Comment: It also happens in IE and Edge.